# Android 13+ Storage Permission

Tags: android, android-api-33

I need some help with the external storage permissions in Android 13+.
I have an app which plays old 8 bit retro music files. I have to update my App to Api 33 and can not use the permission READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE anymore. So when I use the permission READ_MEDIA_AUDIO the files can not be found because they are no typical music files. They can have many different extensions like mod, s3m, zip or even begin with the extension as file name.
Trying to have access to all files will be rejected by the PlayStore team. A file picker is not really a good solution and not very user friendly. I have already implemented a built-in file browser which is very easy to use and has a nice user experience. I have to replace/delete this browser when I have no access to all files. So what are my options now? What is Googles idea how to handle the permission for such unknown file types?

Comment: `they are no typical music files` Well what are they? And which file extension used?

Comment: `have a file browser at the moment which is very easy to use and has a nice user experience` Ok. But why are you telling? What does it have to do with your app?

Comment: Are those music files all over the place or in one directory only?

Comment: They are all over the place and have different extensions like mod s3m xm zip mod.xyz and so on